# Dump of WikiLeaks

Tags: data-request, leak

Does a dump or scrape of WikiLeaks exist? I'm thinking of an equivalent to Wikipedia's database download: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

So far, I haven't found direct access to its publicly released data. It seems surprising to me that this wouldn't exist.

However, I have found the diplomatic cables dataset behind [cablegatesearch](https://cablegatesearch.wikileaks.org/search.php), which is linked to at the bottom of that page: http://cryptome.org/z/z.7z. I'm not sure where this subset of data came from.

Comment: IIRC You'll never get all of their data (unencrypted). They distributed encrypted ZIPs after the Snowden episode that have not been decrypted to date AFAIK - I have them waiting on an external HD ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

October the 18th 2016: https://file.wikileaks.org/file/ was made publicly visible and file dates and timestamps changed to 1984.

Comment: Interesting. Was there any reason the timestamps were changed to 1984?

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE:** the link and details below are currently not available. For details, see http://www.joshwieder.net/search/label/wlstorage.net

---

---

You can find the torrent links for all the Wikileaks data on the [**wlstorage.net**](http://wlstorage.net/) site.

You can either download everything, or select files by "project", as folders or single files: [torrents](http://wlstorage.net/torrent/) (1827 in total at time of posting).

You can also see some data before torrenting - [link](http://wlstorage.net/file/).

**Details:**

> - torrent.tar contains the entire /torrent/ directory.
> - file.torrent contains file.tar file as torrent - RECOMMENDED, PLEASE USE THAT FOR ENTIRE FILE COLLECTION!
> - files-all.torrent is the same, contains entire file collection, but they are not packed. Choose either suits you best.

---

If you want a torrent file for a specific project, an example is:

```
http://wlstorage.net/torrent/zimbabwe-military-election.pdf.torrent
```

An example of a folder is this:

```
http://wlstorage.net/torrent/sarah-palin-hack-2008/
```

with individual torrent files inside.

Comment: The link is broken now.

Comment: More details http://www.joshwieder.net/search/label/wlstorage.net

Comment: https://file.wikileaks.org/torrent/