# Data with trips

Tags: data-request

Any idea if there`s any source from where I can get publicly available data of trip details?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the only source I know is a freedom of information request to NYC's Taxi & Limousine Commission made by [FiveThirtyEight](http://fivethirtyeight.com/). The [data are avaible on this Github repo](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/uber-tlc-foil-responsefivethirty).

Part of the data are also directly [available through an API on OpenDataSoft](https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/?q=uber&sort=modified) if you prefer ;). Disclaimer: I work for OpenDataSoft.

There are not a lot of trip details but it's a good start. Hope it will help though.

Cheers

Comment: Terpo, could you please disclose your affiliation with OpenDataSoft in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, sorry I'll try not to forget next time

Comment: Your answer actually describes data for UBER rides, which was obtained by TLC and shared with 538.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is actually for UBER rides. The NYC Taxi data was FOIA'd by Chris Whong in 2014. (It's a fun story to read, too.)

**[FOILing NYC’s Taxi Trip Data](http://chriswhong.com/open-data/foil_nyc_taxi/)**

[Simple download](http://www.andresmh.com/nyctaxitrips/) - or as a [torrent](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4088/1511)

You can now get the data directly from the Taxi & Limousine Commission  (TLC) - [LINK](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml)