# Tagged (non-anonymized) GPS driver trip database

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, weather, transportation, traffic

The AXA Kaggle challenge [Driver Telematics Analysis](https://www.kaggle.com/c/axa-driver-telematics-analysis) provides a dataset of over 50,000 anonymized driver trips.

Are there open databases of tagged, non-anonymized trips, with several trips for each driver, with car ID identified (if the driver drives several different cars), that could serve as  training data for a data science newbie, and that could be distorted (jitter, noise) to test the robustness of driver detection/clustering algorithms (since we know the ground truth)?

Weather conditions could be a plus.

I am checking the [Publicly available taxi GPS data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/publicly-available-taxi-gps-data) aside.

Comment: Would you still have the `Driver Telematics Analysis` dataset available somewhere for sharing? It looks like meamwhile it has been removed from Kaggle but I would love to play around a bit with it.

Comment: Not here where I am right now. I could check back on my NAS at work, but no promises

Comment: I'm recovered a couple of files, about 2 Gb total. I'll be uploading that on an ephemeral location

Comment: Do you still have the data ? Can you share it with me ? Thanks

Comment: I could do that in a couple of days

Comment: https://archive.org/details/kaggledriver

Comment: I did not find it, excellent suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenStreetMap hosts **[GPS Traces](http://www.openstreetmap.org/traces)** that are uploaded by the community. Not all are for driving, but you can probably screen GPS tracks for total distance to find driving ones. Or screen for users that meet a criteria, like [this one](http://www.openstreetmap.org/user/Leon%20K/traces)

Files are downloadable as [GPX format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format), which has many libraries that support parsing and analyzing.

Bulk download of OSM's traces is possible: [Blog post](https://blog.openstreetmap.org/2013/04/12/bulk-gpx-track-data/) and [download site](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/gps/)

[image]

With GPS coordinates and time you could join to a global weather database ([example](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4243/1511)).