# Running statistics from real users

Tags: data-request, geospatial

There are plenty of mobile applications where you save the running route you took with some stats like speed, distance, duration etc.

Here is an example from one of those apps:

[image]

So, I tried to google for any open dataset (global or country specific) with the coordinates and the stats from those routes. Of course without personal details.

Are you aware of any dataset like this one?

Edit: I am interested on walking/running routes and not driving routes. So, the suggested link in the comments is not related with my question. Although, it could be used as an alternative in case nothing else is available.

Comment: The answer on this question may also apply to yours -  [Tagged (non-anonymized) GPS driver trip database](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7397/tagged-non-anonymized-gps-driver-trip-database)

Comment: It could be an alternative solution, but let's see if anyone could come up with running/walking dataset instead of driving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Street Map users can upload their GPS traces to the website and label them.

There are about 4000 traces with the 'Running' label. You can find the individual traces here: https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces/tag/Running

There's a similar number of traces with the 'Walking' label: https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces/tag/Walking