# Any AVL raw and open data?

Tags: data-request, public-transport, traffic

Does anybody know any Automatic Vehicle Location (GPS) raw data source for transportation analysis? (Except [SFMTA](https://www.sfmta.com/))

Comment: related? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7398/1511

Answer (score 2):

[Phoenix has AVL datasets, and some other documents](https://www.phoenix.gov/find-it/Pages/results.aspx?k=avl)

Comment: thanks Albert,
actually there is a sample file in there but I couldn't find any daily data...